# sublime text suffix mapping

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, file-extension, sublimetext2, text-coloring

is it possible to map the suffix of files opened by sublime text 2 to be similar to other languages to get the text coloring? for example, when i open a *.cu file, this isn't recognize by sublime text as a valid file extension, so it opens the file and there are no text coloring in there at all. however if you open a php or c++ files, the the file will be recognized as valid file extension, and there will be text coloring, making it much easier to read.

I know text wrangler has this feature, and you cam map *.cu file extension to be like c++ so when you open a .cu file, the text coloring will be similar to a c++ file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.

Please see:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/

->

*Map file formats to syntax highlighting*

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to find it but some how wasn't able to